# Create an object for a car that displays each of its properties in <li>

Tags: javascript, html

I want the car properties to be printed for the li tag on the page. I mean to show name and other properties like a list.

```js
let car = {
      name: "benz",
      type: "mercedes",
      price: 5000
    }

    var propertyName = ['name', 'type', 'price'];

    let ulCreate = document.createElement('ul');

    document.body.appendChild(ulCreate);

    for (var prop in propertyName) {
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = propertyName[prop] + " :" + car[propertyName[prop]];
      ulCreate.appendChild(li);
    }
```

```html
<body>
    
    <div>
         <ul id="carr">
         </ul>
         <br/><br/>
   
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your `car` object is not valid JS syntax. `return this.name + this.type + this.price` can only occur inside a `function`. Also, **never** use `document.write`. Next you get a NodeList using querySelectorAll, but never do anything with it. Instead, you use the same name of the variable in a `for...in` loop (which doesn't make sense at all).

Comment: Once you got your solution, I recommend using [the description list element `<dl>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) instead of `<ul>` for the sake of semantics and accessibility.

Comment: javascript is wrong, the "car object" you are using is not correct. Car object is not an array so you can't use it in a for loop.
You have made ul li querySelectorAll but it is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, then this should give you some idea.

```js
const myCar = {
   name: "benz",
   type: "mercedes",
   price: 5000,
};
 
function renderCar(car) {
   const listElement = document.getElementById("carr");
   listElement.innerHTML += `
      <li>name: ${car.name}</li>
      <li>type: ${car.type}</li>
      <li>price: ${car.price}</li>
   `
}
renderCar(myCar);
```

```html
<body>
     <div>
         <ul id="carr"></ul>
         <br /><br />
     </div>
</body>
```

- If we have multiple cars (an array of objects), we can also iterate over the array and display an `<li>` for every property of every member.

Comment: Consider writing logic in a way that doesn't hardcode the properties (.name, .type, .price etc) since it will allow the JSON to have additional keys and be automatically populated to the list.
And consider not using innerHTML and creating DOM elements and appending

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't run for me. Is it may be for the use of $?

Comment: The `${}` are so called [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and should work if you’re not using Internet Explorer.

Comment: Exactly, it's a matter of a nicer syntax instead of writing `'<li>name: ' + car.name + '</li>'`

Comment: I rendered the example interactive @Yasaman_Badeli. Does it work for you here? If not, what are the error messages?

Comment: Actually it works here, but it does not work when I use the same code in Dreamweaver program.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of cars you can do something like this:

```js
let cars = [{
    name: "benz",
    type: "mercedes",
    price: 5000
  },
  {
    name: "fiat",
    type: "punto",
    price: 6000
  },
  {
    name: "bmw",
    type: "i900",
    price: 7000
  },
  {
    name: "toyota",
    type: "corola",
    price: 8000
  }
]

let carsList = document.getElementById("carr");

cars.forEach(function(car, index) {
  let name = document.createElement("li");
  let type = document.createElement("li");
  let price = document.createElement("li");

  name.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Name: " + car.name));
  type.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Type: " + car.type));
  price.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Price: " + car.price));

  carsList.appendChild(name);
  carsList.appendChild(type);
  carsList.appendChild(price);
})
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <ul id="carr"></ul>
    <br /><br />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It is also a solution for one car. Just remove forEach function.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply it as follows.
You can create javascript in html and place property on objects.

```js
let car = {
      name: "benz",
      type: "mercedes",
      price: 5000
    }

    var propertyName = ['name', 'type', 'price'];

    let ulCreate = document.createElement('ul');

    document.body.appendChild(ulCreate);

    for (var prop in propertyName) {
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = propertyName[prop] + " :" + car[propertyName[prop]];
      ulCreate.appendChild(li);
    }
```

```js
let car = [{
      name: "benz",
      type: "mercedes",
      price: 5000
    },{
      name: "A3",
      type: "audi",
      price: 8000
    },{
      name: "focus",
      type: "ford",
      price: 2500
    }]

    var propertyName = ['name', 'type', 'price'];

    let ulCreate = document.createElement('ul');

    document.body.appendChild(ulCreate);

    for (var cr in car) {
     for (var prop in propertyName) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = propertyName[prop]  + ":" + car[cr][propertyName[prop]]
        ulCreate.appendChild(li);
      }
    }
```